# jquery datatables serverside ajax with asp.net webMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatable

I'm using jquery Datatables (1.10.13) in a ASP.net project (non-MVC) in which "GridBooksList" is a DataTable, requesting to "GetBooks()" method by an Ajax call.

I'm not getting success to invoke "GetBooks" method by using Datatables ServerSide Ajax call. Getting error:

***table id=GridBooksList - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row '0', column1***

Following are the code i'm working with:

**PageLibrary.aspx**

```
<table id="GridBooksList" class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
<thead style="background-color: #336699; color: white;">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:20%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
        </th>
        <th style="width:10%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblIdentityNo" runat="server" Text="Serial No."></asp:Label>
        </th>
        <th style="width:10%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblNationality" runat="server" Text="Author"></asp:Label>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="table-tbody">
</tbody>
```

```
<script>
try{
$('#GridBooksList').DataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "PageLibrary.aspx/GetBooks",
        "data": "{'FromDate':'" + fromdate + "','ToDate':'" + todate + "'}",
        "aoColumns": [
                       { "sName": "NAME" },
                       { "sName": "SERIAL_NUMBER"},
                       { "sName": "AUTHOR" }
        ]
        });
}catch(ee)
{
//getting error here//
//table id=GridBooksList - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row '0', column1
}
</script>
```

**PageLibrary.aspx.cs**

```
//Model Class //
public class BookDetail
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string SERIAL_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string AUTHOR { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
    public static string GetBooks(string FromDate, string ToDate)
    {
        try
        {
            // getting data from database server here //
            List<BookDetail> booklist = ENT.Database.SqlQuery<BookDetail>('sql query here').ToList();
            JavaScriptSerializer JavaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(booklist); 
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your issue may lie with the sql which you've omitted with 'sql query here'.  Can you supply the actual sql query used?

Comment: no issue with sql query as it is returning data in the booklist..we have seen by putting breakpoint.. sql query is SELECT name,serial,author from table_books.

Comment: It might be worth enabling break on exceptions for the client console as well as your C# IDE which I guess is VIsual Studio? That way you can see what is causing the error and potentially how to solve it.

Comment: Problem is Ajax call is not hitting the "GetBooks" method in C#. SQL query is working fine that i checked by calling "GetBooks" method on Page_Load.

Comment: In the console/network tab of your developer tools, do you see the request to the WebMethod?

Comment: NO, it's just coming to catch section after "bServerSide":true,